# Entire matrix row takes only last value of 3 numeric values

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, statistics

I am trying to block sample a simulated dataset where there are 100 values, and putting the blocks into a 98x3 [matrix](/questions/tagged/matrix) where each row corresponds to a block. My code looks like this:

```r
e <- rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
Y <- rnorm(100)

Y[1] = 1 + e[1]
Y[2] = 1 + 0.5*Y[1] + e[2] - 0.5*e[1]
Y[3] = 1 + 0.5*Y[2] + e[3] - 0.5*e[2] - 0.25*e[1]

for(i in 4:100){
  Y[i] <- 1 + 0.5*Y[i-1] + e[i] - 0.5*e[i-1] - 0.25*e[i-2]
}

B <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 98, ncol = 3)

for(a in 1:98){
  B[a,] <- Y[a:a+2]
}
```

I did it this way since without the loop, `**B[1,] <- Y[1:3]**` works to replace the row of the matrix.

However, after running the code, each row of B are the same three numbers which are equal to `Y[a+2]` for the corresponding row, `B[a,]`.

Is there a way around this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I didn't check the rest of your code, but `a:a+2` is the same as just `a+2`, try `a:(a+2)`

Comment: ahaha that worked. silly me. thank you so much!